# How to bind own file extension to python script with console suppressed

Tags: python, file-association

First of all, sorry for my english.

I have created my own file extension and bound it to my `python` script with `assoc` and `ftype`:

```
assoc .iv=IV.Measurement
ftype IV.Measurement=python /path/to/my/script/myscript.py %1
```

It works like a charm.
But if I want to suppress the console it shows me a dialog to select default app to open my file and proposes `python.exe` as default.
If I try:

```
ftype IV.Measurement=python /path/to/my/script/myscript.pyw %1
```

it works and shows me console.
If I try:

```
ftype IV.Measurement=pythonw /path/to/my/script/myscript.py %1
```

or

```
ftype IV.Measurement=pythonw /path/to/my/script/myscript.pyw %1
```

it makes me choose default app.

And if I choose `pythonw.exe` as default it try to run my file as `pythonw` app bypassing my script, like this:

```
pythonw my_iv_file.iv
```

In spite of this I can to run my app from cmd:

```
pythonw /path/to/my/script/myscript.pyw my_iv_file.iv
```

How can I bind my file extension to `pythonw`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work without displaying a console using these commands to associate the file type with the script:

```
assoc .iv=IV.Measurement
ftype IV.Measurement=C:\Python27\pythonw.exe "C:\Test Files\myscript.pyw" %1 %*
```

The main things to note are I used a full paths to both`pythonw.exe`as well as to `myscript.pyw`, plus backslashes (`"\"`) were used as path separator characters. You'll also need to enclose any paths in double quotes if they contain any space characters.

Afterwards when`my_iv_file.iv`was double-clicked to open, the value of`sys.argv`in `myscript.pyw`was:

```
["C:\Test Files\myscript.pyw", "C:\Test Files\my_iv_file.iv"]
```